# Amazon's S3 doesn't work with requests using https

Tags: https, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I use Amazon's S3 and CloudFront for assets delivery. I have specified CORS configuration at S3 bucket:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

So when I open app using http it's ok. But when I open it using https it says

```
Origin https://<app-domain> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is CloudFront bug. It caches first origin that accesses S3 and doesn't allow another origins in future. As a workaround [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=114646) can be used.